# Photoshop: Copying a single layer to a next PSD

Tags: adobe-photoshop, copy-paste, layers, psd

For the past 20 mins I've trying to copy a layer from one PSD to the next but to no avail.
I'm a PS noob so please could someone tell me the steps in which to achieve this short term goal :) 
Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the layer and select from the menu:

```
Layer -> Duplicate layer...
```

Then choose document and name of the copied layer.

Answer (score 1):

If both files are opened simply drag your layer to the other file.

But you have to drag it on the canvas, dragging to the tab doesn't work.